Создание полноценного приложения на QT(C++)
Я написал свой проект на C++ в Qt, все работает, но при поиске информации о том, как сделать из проекта полноценное приложение, которое можно перекинуть на другой компьютер и оно бы так же работало, ничего толкового не нашел.

Я нашел способ, при котором проект сохраняется в папку со всеми необходимыми библиотеками и уже эту папку можно пересылать и при запуске exe-шника в ней все будет работать, но я хотел бы, чтобы это выглядело, как просто иконка на рабочем столе на которую нужно просто нажать и программа бы заработала. Не подскажете как такое можно реализовать?

Если кому интересно, вот проект Машина Атвуда на GitHub.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Иконки на рабочем столе запускают исполняемый файл, который где-то лежит со всеми необходимыми библиотеками и ресурсами.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@DIMETRIIS Совершенно глупо сформулированный вопрос. Судя по тексту Вы делаете под Windows? Создание установщика проекта - InnoSetup -  тык, сюда (https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) под Linux? либо собираете пакет (под разные версии ОС - разные способы), либо юзайте Qt Installer Framework (тут уж разбирайтесь сами).
